# Error importing compiled typescript code: TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm having trouble building a package in typescript that can be used by other javascript projects. I can't find the right combination of target, module, and syntax to get classes to work.

tl;dr:
What settings do I use when compiling a typescript project to let other projects import and use the source files?

I'm building a react app using typescript, using code I've extracted into a package so many projects can use it. I've called it `js-utilities` and it includes some exported functions and classes. One of my service classes imports and extends a helper class:

```
import {Accessor, DataCache} from "@whiterook6/js-utilities/lib";

export class CloudServerAccessor extends Accessor {
    private readonly cache: DataCache;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.cache = DataCache.build("Cloud Providers");
    }

    // some other stuff

    public getCloudServers = async (file) => {
        const response = await fetch(file, {
            referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
        });
        await this.checkResponse(response);
    }
}
```

The code compiles without errors, but when I run it in the browser I get this error:

```
TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'
CloudServerAccessor CloudServerAccessor.ts:60
```

If I change the import to `/src`, then it seems to work:

```
import {Accessor} from "myPackage/js-utilities/src";
import {DataCache} from "myPackage/js-utilities/lib";
```

So something about what I'm building and publishing is breaking it. I've read that it might be because a class is being transpiled then imported and used in typescript again, but other than that all the solutions I've found for `class constructors must be invoked with 'new'` have revolved around specific issues for other packages. Should I use ES6, ESNext, etc. for the target, and what about the modules?

If I import from `src` everything works fine, but that feels like I don't really understand what I'm doing, and I might as well publish a typescript package then.

The package folder looks like this:

```
lib/
  Accessor.js
  Accessor.d.ts
  ... other files
  index.js
  index.d.ts
node_modules/
  ... other files
src
  Accessor.ts
  ...
  index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
...
```

The source for `src/Accessor.ts` looks like this:

```
export class Accessor {
  public async checkResponse (response: Response){
    if (response.ok) {
      return;
    }

    const text = await response.text();
    if (text) {
      switch (response.status) {
        case 401:
          throw new Error(`Error 401: Unauthorized: ${text}`);
        case 404:
          throw new Error(`Error 404: Not Found: ${text}`);
        case 429:
          throw new Error(`Error 429: Too Many Requests: ${text}`);
      }
    // more of the same for other cases.
  };
}
```

and index.ts in the `js-utilities` package looks like this:

```
export {DataCache} from "./DataCache";
export {Accessor} from "./Accessor";
```

`tsconfig.json` in the `js-utilities` package looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

The resulting `lib` folder in the compiled package has files like this:

```
lib/Accessor.js
lib/Accessor.d.ts
...
lib/index.js
lib/index.d.ts
...
```

And the consuming project that's actually throwing the error is built with webpack using babel-loader.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify or add the "index.ts" file with the content:

```
export Accessor from "myPackage/js-utilities/src"; //change it by the correct package
export DataCache from "myPackage/js-utilities/lib";//change it by the correct package
```

Comment: You mean the index.ts file in the package, right? I've posted my index.ts file as well. I think it already does the exporting you're looking for, but I don't understand why the index.ts file would include the folder it's in, since it doesn't know about where files are built.

Comment: The index.ts file tells Typescript that those classes, methods, or other declared value, are "exported" as public to be used without the full package name, yet each folder could have an index.ts file as well.

Comment: So, if I understand you, the index.ts file above that I added to my question isn't enough? It needs to export the name and folder of the package as well?

Comment: @whiterook6 I can't find your index.ts file, where is it?

Comment: It's just this: export {DataCache} from "./DataCache";
export {Accessor} from "./Accessor";

Comment: Where DataCache.ts is?